# Stopping from changing form before parsing

Tags: c#

I'm wanting to move to the next form but I put in a try catch when parsing the items, when the next button is pressed it catches if there is a problem but goes to the next form anyway. Is there anyway to stop this by keeping it on the same form but keeping the ability to move to the next form in the next button?

Thanks

```
private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ParseItems();
        Formchange();
    }
public void ParseItems()
    {
        try
        {
            Amount = decimal.Parse(DepositTextBox1.Text);

            try
            {
                WeekInterestRate = decimal.Parse(WeekIntTextBox.Text);
                try
                {
                    TwoWeekInterestRate = decimal.Parse(TWeekIntTextBox.Text);
                    try
                    {
                        MonthInterestRate = decimal.Parse(MonthIntTextBox.Text);
                        try
                        {
                            ThreeMonthInterestRate = decimal.Parse(ThreeMonthIntTextBox.Text);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in numerical form", "Input Error");
                            ThreeMonthIntTextBox.Focus();
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in numerical form", "Input Error");
                        MonthIntTextBox.Focus();

                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in numerical form","Input Error");
                    TWeekIntTextBox.Focus();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in numerical form", "Input Error");
                WeekIntTextBox.Focus();
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in numerical form","Input Error");
            DepositTextBox1.Focus();
        }

    }


    //changes to the next form
        public void Formchange()
        {
            Form2 f3 = new Form2();
            f3.Show(this);
            Hide();
        }
```

Comment: check [Decimal.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx), you don't need try catch

Answer (score 0):

just change  your code to the following

```
private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ParseItems();                
        }
    public void ParseItems()
        {
            try
            {
                Amount = decimal.Parse(DepositTextBox1.Text);

                try
                {
                    WeekInterestRate = decimal.Parse(WeekIntTextBox.Text);
                    try
                    {
                        TwoWeekInterestRate = decimal.Parse(TWeekIntTextBox.Text);
                        try
                        {
                            MonthInterestRate = decimal.Parse(MonthIntTextBox.Text);
                            try
                            {
                                ThreeMonthInterestRate = decimal.Parse(ThreeMonthIntTextBox.Text);
                                //here how you can achieve this 
                                 Formchange(); 
                            }
                            catch
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in numerical form", "Input Error");
                                ThreeMonthIntTextBox.Focus();
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in numerical form", "Input Error");
                            MonthIntTextBox.Focus();

                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in numerical form","Input Error");
                        TWeekIntTextBox.Focus();
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in numerical form", "Input Error");
                    WeekIntTextBox.Focus();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter values in numerical form","Input Error");
                DepositTextBox1.Focus();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This approach:

```
public bool ParseItems()
{
   bool Success=false;
   try
    {
        Amount = decimal.Parse(DepositTextBox1.Text);
        Success=true;
    }
   catch(Exception e){
   Success=false;
    }
}

if(Success)
return true;

return false;
}

private void nextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ParseItems())
    {
     Formchange();
    }
}
```

Comment: he can achieve this without changing the method  signature

Answer (score 0):

update your function with return value

```
    public bool ParseItems()
```

inside the catch block add a return statement as a last action (after you call Focus();)

```
    return false;
```

add return statement to the end of your function

```
    return true;
```

update you calling code

```
     if(ParseItems())
         Formchange();
```